# When I deploy my nodejs app on heroku, build success but got a "Application Error"

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have already run my nodejs app successfully on my localhost, but when I deploy it on heroku, build success, but I got a "Application Error", when I use "heroku logs", it show like this:
[console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aSqb.png)

I can't figure out what's wrong with my app, hope to get your help, thanks!

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --harmony test",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production pm2 start index.js --node-args='--harmony' --name 'adolt-blog'"
  },
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "config-lite": "^1.5.0",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^1.3.2",
    "cross-env": "^3.1.3",
    "ejs": "^2.5.2",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "express-formidable": "^1.0.0",
    "express-session": "^1.14.2",
    "express-winston": "^2.0.0",
    "marked": "^0.3.6",
    "moment": "^2.17.0",
    "mongolass": "^2.3.2",
    "objectid-to-timestamp": "^1.3.0",
    "sha1": "^1.1.1",
    "winston": "^2.3.0",
    "pm2": "^2.2.3",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0"
  }
}
```

and index.js

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var config = require('config-lite');
var routes = require('./routes');
var pkg = require('./package');
var winston = require('winston');
var expressWinston = require('express-winston');

var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(session({
    name: config.session.key, 
    secret: config.session.secret, 
    cookie: {
        maxAge: config.session.maxAge 
    },
    store: new MongoStore({
        url: config.mongodb 
    }),
  saveUninitializedSession: true,
  resaveSession: true
}));

app.use(flash());
app.use(require('express-formidable')({
    uploadDir: path.join(__dirname, 'public/img'),
    keepExtensions: true 
}));

app.locals.blog = {
  // title: pkg.name,
  // description: pkg.description
  title: 'Adolt\'s Blog',
  description: 'Learn Node.js'
};

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user = req.session.user;
  res.locals.success = req.flash('success').toString();
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error').toString();
  next();
});

app.use(expressWinston.logger({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)({
      json: true,
      colorize: true
    }),
    new winston.transports.File({
      filename: 'logs/success.log'
    })
  ]
}));

routes(app);

app.use(expressWinston.errorLogger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      json: true,
      colorize: true
    }),
    new winston.transports.File({
      filename: 'logs/error.log'
    })
  ]
}));

if (module.parent) {
  module.exports = app;
} else {
  const port = process.env.PORT;
  app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(`${pkg.name} listening on port ${port}`);
  });
}
```

Comment: Please, provide the full index.js ....

Comment: @Lucas Katayama yesterday .Please take a look, thanks.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have any problem... try this http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/use-pm2-with-cloud-providers/

Comment: @Lucas Katayama Thanks a lot! It does help! After adding main.js as the documentation and modifying the Procfile, the page finally shows! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @Lucas Katayama, the problem finally solved.

First, add `main.js` according to the [use-pm2-with-cloud-providers](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/use-pm2-with-cloud-providers).

And then modify the `Procfile` like this

```
web: node main.js
```

Finally, rebuild your app and see if it works!

Hope it can help! Good luck!